# Russian GIS Data

Tags: data, geocoding, routing, map-service, point-of-interest

Which companies are the best suppliers of vector, geocoding, imagery, and POI data in Russia?   Which companies provide a complete service (which includes the above data types and also routing, rendering, etc.)?

Comment: https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal hope you know the Russian language

Comment: I dont understand, what exactly do u need.
PM me (u may write rus), may be i can help.

Answer (score 3):

Check the sources of Yandex Maps [here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8) and [here](http://legal.yandex.ru/maps_termsofuse/). (hope you understand Russian).

Few more links for you:

- http://www.resident.ru/data/default.htm
- http://www.geocenter-consulting.ru/
- http://www.dongis.ru/
- http://www.automaps.ru/
- http://www.kami.ru/
- http://www.transnavi.com/